# href dynamic generation of link not working with php. prints but doesnt work

Tags: php, casting

I am developing an API call with PHP for FreshDesk and would love some insight. I am trying to page the results of the JSON call, and have been successful so far. The problem is that my direct links are working but the dynamic ones aren't.

I have tried all kinds of order, casting, type changes, and other tweaks but to no avail. Plus the company's programmer is not even around to help... Here is an excerpt of the code.. more on github.

```
class MyPaginator {
  public $tickets;
  public $wantedStr;
  public $pageNum;

  function __construct($number) {
    $this->$pageNum = $number;
    $this->$wantedStr = $addr . $this->$pageNum;
  }
}
function getPageDecision() {
  $selected = parse_url(curPageURL())['query'];
  if (empty($selected)) {
     $selected = '1';
  } else {
     $selected = str_replace('page=', '', $selected);
  }
 return $selected;
}

$paginator = new MyPaginator(getPageDecision());

$previousPage = ((int)$paginator->$pageNum) - 1;
$nextPage = ((int)$paginator->$pageNum) + 1;

function showPageMenu(){
echo '<br /><div class="pagination">
 <a href="http://tickets.cloudlink.biz/?page='.strval($previousPage).'">&laquo;</a>
 <a href="http://tickets.cloudlink.biz/?page=1"'.activeClass('1').'>1</a>
 <a href="http://tickets.cloudlink.biz/?page=2"'.activeClass('2').'>2</a>
 <a href="http://tickets.cloudlink.biz/?page=3"'.activeClass('3').'>3</a>
 <a href="http://tickets.cloudlink.biz/?page=4"'.activeClass('4').'>4</a>
 <a href="http://tickets.cloudlink.biz/?page=5"'.activeClass('5').'>5</a>
 <a href="http://tickets.cloudlink.biz/?page=6"'.activeClass('6').'>6</a>
 <a href="http://tickets.cloudlink.biz/?page='.strval($nextPage).'">&raquo; 
</a>
</div>';
}
```

I expect the result of clicking the forward or backward buttons to lead me to /?page= dynamically because the number ones are working..... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not using the global keyword for referencing the correct scope for the function. Problem is solved.